# Is a simple MySql Database possible?

Tags: mysql, database, insert, foreign-keys

Steps:

1. I want a registered user to be able to insert values into a table.
2. Those values would only be able to be seen or edited by the user. (a few rows)

I have a registration/login page and insert form page complete and they can add do their respective jobs.

Here's the problem and i realize it probably a super simple answer:

How do I link the registration/login username to the values that I'm entering so that only that username has access to it?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a MySQL user for each registered user and protect their data at the DB level. That's usually overkill for a web application.

What you probably want here is enforcing data owner at the data access layer. Associate the data to the user and restrict any data queries or updates to that user, i.e. any insert, update, select SQL statements would include the user id as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Session Variables to Bring over the LoginID and then  add that to the other table. I'm going to post another question on that.